# deselect an item when a particular item is selected in listbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listbox

I have listbox on a windows form in VB.NET, the list box contains list of jobs, which are populated from a database.
The values selected on the listbox are then used to built up a SQL statement which is then sent to create a report.
My problem is, I want the list box to deselect all other items when one particular item is selected. Basically my problem is, when I selected item 0 (which is list of all jobs)I want all other items to be unselected and if any other items are selected, Item 0 must be unselected. 
Item 0 = is basically and group of jobs.
remaining Items = individual jobs.
Below is the code which i'm using to load listbox

```
Public Sub CommandCollection()
        Dim connetionString As String = Nothing
        Dim connection As SqlConnection
        Dim command As SqlCommand
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter()
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        ListBox1.Enabled = False
        BtnClosedJobActualQuoteViewer_Click.Enabled = True
        Dim sql As String = Nothing
        connetionString = "Data Source=DEV-TST235\SQLEXPRESS2005;Initial Catalog=TSTracker;Integrated Security=True"
        sql = "SELECT -1 JobId, '<All>' JobNumber" & _
                " UNION " & _
                " SELECT * from (SELECT DISTINCT Jobs.JobId,RTRIM(Jobs.JobNumber) JobNumber FROM Jobs INNER JOIN" & _
                " Companies (NOLOCK) ON Jobs.CustomerID = Companies.CompanyID INNER JOIN" & _
                " JobHistory (NOLOCK) ON Jobs.JobID = JobHistory.JobID" & _
                " WHERE  (JobHistory.modifiedDate > '" & StartDate.Value.ToShortDateString & "') AND (JobHistory.modifiedDate < '" & EndDate.Value.ToShortDateString & "') AND (JobHistory.Description = 'Job Closed')" & _
                ")a ORDER BY JobNumber"
        connection = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
        Try
            connection.Open()
            command = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
            adapter.SelectCommand = command
            adapter.Fill(ds)
            adapter.Dispose()
            command.Dispose()
            connection.Close()
            ListBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
            ListBox1.ValueMember = "JobId"
            ListBox1.DisplayMember = "JobNumber"
            ListBox1.ClearSelected()
            If ListBox1.Items.Count > 1 Then
                ListBox1.Enabled = True
            Else
                ListBox1.Enabled = False
                ListBox1.DataSource = Nothing
                ListBox1.Items.Clear()
                BtnClosedJobActualQuoteViewer_Click.Enabled = False
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ")
        End Try
    End Sub
```

and below is the code where i can manage to unselect the selected items when an item at index=0 is selected which is half of the answer but i also want it to happen in the other way, i mean if other items as selected other then the item at index = 0 then the item at index= 0 must be unselected.

```
 Dim index As Integer
            index = ListBox1.SelectedIndex
            If index = 0 Then
                ListBox1.SelectedItems.Clear()
                ListBox1.SetSelected(0, True)
            ElseIf index <> 0 Then
                ListBox1.SetSelected(0, False)
            End If
        End If
```

Comment: Show us your code and where you are stuck.

Comment: I have added the code where im stuck

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
    ' If only 1 item is selected, then do nothing
    If ListBox1.SelectedItems.Count > 1 Then
        ' If there is more than one item selected and 
        ' one of those items is the first item
        If ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
            ' Clear all selected items
            ListBox1.SelectedItems.Clear()
            ' Select only the first item
            ListBox1.SetSelected(0, True)
        End If
    End If
```